# Non-repeating data

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly I am brand new to PHP and MySQL.

My goal is to display testimonies from students that are in the database. It display two testimonies but I need them to be two DIFFERENT testimonies. Help please!

```
<div class="block_main_testimonials">
                        <h4>Student Corner</h4>
<?php   
 // Connect to the file above here   
 require "includes/connect.php";  

  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2") 
  or die(mysql_error()); 

  $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ) ; 

?>
                        <div class="one_half">
                            <div class="block_testimonials_2">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <p>“<?php echo $info['quote'] ;?>”</p>

                                        <div class="tail"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="author">
                                      <p><?php echo $info['name'] ; ?>,<span class="position"> <a href="<?php echo $info['url'] ; ?>"> <?php echo $info['department']; ?></a></span></p></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="one_half last">
                            <div class="block_testimonials_2">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <p>“<?php echo $info['quote'] ;?>”</p>

                                        <div class="tail"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="author">
                                      <p><?php echo $info['name'] ; ?>,<span class="position"> <a href="<?php echo $info['url'] ; ?>"> <?php echo $info['department']; ?></a></span></p></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearboth"></div>
```

Comment: use something like this `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM testimonials...`

Comment: What in particular isn't working? If you execute that query directly against your database, are the results okay? Are you getting any error messages, or is the data just not what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only fetched the first row of your resultset.

Make this call again before displaying what you hope will be the second row of your resultset. For best results call it in a loop until your resultset is exhausted.

```
    $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ) ;
```

Except, you've probably figured out by now, the `mysql` interface is considered harmful because it's way too easy for badguys to pwn websites that use it.